# View last cell when i add array of cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to show last cell record in tableview cell. Each time i will add new array in table view. After i will reload the tableview cell. Now its showing the record from first cell. Any one please advice to me how will show last cell .

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TrackDataTimeCell";
TrackDataTimeCell *cell = (TrackDataTimeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TrackDataTimeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (TrackDataTimeCell *) cellChallengeFriends;
        cellChallengeFriends = nil;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
}

if (!cell) {
    cell =(TrackDataTimeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    cell.accessoryView = activityIndicatorView;

}
NSArray *tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", nil];
NSArray *tableData1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"test1", @"test2", nil];


[cell.deleteButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row;


cell.nameList.text= [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.marklist.text= [tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;

}


- (IBAction)addBillingItems:(id)sender
 {

    rowVal=rowVal+1;
    [nameList addObject: self.codeAdd.text];
    [marklist addObject: selectDate];

    [tbl reloadData];

}
```

Please check the example image at http://postimg.org/image/g0dzs0r2p/

I have 5 cells. Now it is showing the first four. After I scroll it shows 5 but I want the last cell to show in first time. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to automatically scroll to the last inserted cell.

```
    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height + 150);
    if ( bottomOffset.y > 0 ) {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
    }
```

The **150** value is to add extra space after the cell in tableView. Its optional i.e. you can use it if you want extra space after the cell

Comment: @Ahamed: One more help i want

Comment: @Ahamed: one text box is there. Its readonly now. Here what i want means Just i click that text box will call one action.

Comment: YOu want to perform an action/selector, call a method on textBox's click? ryt?

Comment: @Ahamed: Yes before i called the method from click the button action. Now i want to call methos when click the UITextfiled

Comment: Take `UITextFieldDelegate` in your **.h** file, then in **.m** file's `viewDidLoad`, `textField.delegate = self;` and then add this method in your **.m** file `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    [self myMethod]; 
    return YES; 
}`

Comment: @Ahamed ; i have two text filed in same page. But i want only one box will click means access the  method.

Comment: @Ahamed : i will try then let you know

Comment: So In `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method add this ... `if(textField == YourDesiredTextFieldName) [self myMethod];`

Comment: @Ahamed: Thanks ya.. it working but i want that text filed is ready only or not editable! how we can make it? Before i have used  self.dateTime.userInteractionEnabled=NO; for that text field for ready only. But now if i give this statement action will not call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the tableview frame less.If you have iPhone tableview frame then set the frame as cgrectmake(0,0,320,430).If that will not solve your problem then add uitableview:viewforheaderinsection method.Just add uiview and set frame as cgrectmake(0,0,320,1).This will set the frame for the table as well as show all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy solution to your problem. Just use the tableView's method

```
    [tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: rowVal inSection:0]
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                              animated:YES];
```

Just call it after `[tbl reloadData]`